# Have the potential therapeutic applications of cell fusion between cancer cells and neural cells been investigated?

Tags: cancer, reference-request, cells, therapy

Studies have appeared on the possible role that cell fusion plays in the formation of certain cancers. For instance, Sitar et al. (2019) have [looked into](https://www.haematologica.org/article/view/1509/6705) the process of cell fusion in the formation of erythroleukemia.

However, research has also been done on the potential therapeutic effects of cell fusion to tumour immunotheraphy, see e.g. this [article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3187729/#B13) by Pedrazzoli et al. (2011) and [this one](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3187729/#B13) by Sullivan and Eggan (2006). For instance, in the former an [article](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/7507262/) by Guo et al. (1994) is mentioned in which researchers fused B-cells with carcinoma hepatoma cells to create a vaccine, which resulted in hybrid cells that lost their tumorigenicity and became immunogenic.

I am interested in a particular type of heterotypic cell fusion. More specifically, I am curious whether biomedical research has been done on the potential therapeutic applications of fusion between neurons and different types of cancer cells. My reasoning is as follows: neurons in the brain do not renew themselves through cell division processes that occur in many other parts of the body. So if neural cells fuse with cancer cells (that grow and divide more quickly than normal cells), the resulting hybrid cell might have lost some of its carcinoid properties - including its tendency towards rapid proliferation.

**Question**: has any research been done on the potential therapeutic applications of cell fusion between neural cells and cancer cells? If so, can you point me towards a relevant reference?

*Note*: I am a mathematican, not a biomedical or pharmaceutical scientist. If my reasoning seems seriously flawed, please enlighten me on the matter. I did try to perform a literature review and hope this question is appropriate for this venue.

Comment: Probably Bio.SE would be a much better place to ask. There are more experts related to the field.

Comment: @user237650 Thank you for the suggestion, I've asked it over there as well: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/111409/have-the-potential-therapeutic-applications-of-cell-fusion-between-cancer-cells

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been cross-posted to Biology.SE